# Replace element of matrix based on rule which involves another element of same matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix, replacement

I am trying to replace 1s row of matrix d iteratively from right by multiplying last element in 1st row with (1-int*dt) to generate 2nd last element. The replacement continues till I reach the 1st element of the row using code below. Can anybody help to let me know where I am going wrong. The code doesn't give error but gives out initial element without doing replacement. I am trying to find out an efficient way to replace elements of the matrix recursively based on certain rules/function. Is ReplacePart best to use, or there is another way?

```
elemOperate[int_, dt_, nas_, nts_] := 
 Module[{d},
  d =  ConstantArray[2, {nas + 1, nts}];
  For[j = nts, j--, 
   d = 
    ReplacePart[d, {1, j_ - 1} :> (1 - int*dt)*d[[1, j]]]
  ];
  Grid[d]
 ]

elemOperate[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4]
```

generates following output:

> ```
> {
> ```

```
   {"2", "2", "2", "2"},
   {"2", "2", "2", "2"},
   {"2", "2", "2", "2"},
   {"2", "2", "2", "2"},
   {"2", "2", "2", "2"}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a fixed version of your code:

```
ClearAll[eOF0, eOF1, eOF2, eOF3]
eOF0[int_, dt_, nas_, nts_] := 
 Module[{d = ConstantArray[2, {nas + 1, nts}]}, 
  For[j = nts, j > 1, j--, d = ReplacePart[d, {1, j - 1} -> (1 - int*dt)*d[[1, j]]]];
  Grid[d]]
eOF0[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4]
```

[image]

and a few alternatives

```
eOF1[int_, dt_, nas_, nts_] := Module[{d = ConstantArray[2, {nas + 1, nts}]}, 
  For[j = nts, j > 1, j--, d[[1, j - 1]] = (1 - int*dt)*d[[1, j]]];   Grid[d]]

eOF2[int_, dt_, nas_, nts_] := Module[{d = ConstantArray[2, {nas + 1, nts}]},
  d[[1]] = Reverse@FoldList[(1 - int dt) # &, d[[1]]]; Grid@d]

eOF3[int_, dt_, nas_, nts_] := Module[{d = ConstantArray[2, {nas + 1, nts}]},
  Table[d[[1, j - 1]] = (1 - int*dt)*d[[1, j]], {j, nts, 2, -1}]; Grid[d]]
```

They give the same result as `eOF0`:

```
eOF1[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4] == eOF2[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4] == 
     eOF3[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4]== eOF0[0.01, 0.1, 4, 4]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks kguler. I like e0F2. However when I  am trying to use  e0F2 as a in code where I have done matrix operation on same matrix, Revese@FoldList is ignoring intermediate steps and just working on the intial array. pl refer to code below

Comment: optionprice[strike1_, nas1_, expn1_, vol1_, int_] := 
 Module[{ds, s, dt, dt1, t, nts, fd},
  ds = 2*strike1/nas1;
  dt = 0.9/(vol1*vol1*nas1* nas1) ;
  nts = IntegerPart [expn1 /dt] + 1;
  dt1 = expn1/nts;
  s = Table[i*ds, {i, 0, nas1 + 1}];
  t = Table [j*dt1, {j, 0, nts}];
  fd = ConstantArray[1, {nas1 + 1, nts}];
  fd = ReplacePart[fd, {i_, nts} :> Max[(s[[i]] - strike1), 0]];
  fd[[1]] = Reverse@FoldList[(1 - int *dt1) # &, fd[[1]]];
  Grid[fd]
  ]

Comment: optionprice[100, 10, 1, 0.2, 0.01] gives following output where last 1st row of last column is 1

Comment: \!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"0.992023968016`", "0.994011992`", "0.996004`", "0.998`", "1"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "0"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "0"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "0"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "0"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "0"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "20"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "40"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "60"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "80"},
{"1", "1", "1", "1", "100"}
},

Comment: Anyway I can use Reverse@FoldList on most updated version of matrix fd please?

Comment: It seems e0F3 works in the most recent code. Thanks for your help